# split new line except digit in unicode file

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have utf_8 .txt file:
greek.txt

```
Blessed is a Man

1. μακάριος
ανήρ
2. ότι
γινώσκει
κύριος
```

I would like to get: greek_r.txt

```
Blessed is a Man

1. μακάριος ανήρ
2. ότι γινώσκει κύριος
```

I used

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import io
import re
f1 = io.open('greek.txt','r',encoding='utf8')
f2 = io.open('greek_r.txt','w',encoding='utf8')

for line in f1:
    f2.write(re.sub(r'\n((?=^[^\d]))', r'\1', line))

f1.close()
f2.close()
```

but is not working, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the input file line by line, thus, your regex cannot "see" across lines, `\n` is the last char in each line and `(?=^[^\d])` just makes no sense as it requires the start of string followed with a char other than a digit.

Use something like:

```
import re, io
with io.open('greek.txt','r',encoding='utf8') as f1:
    with io.open('greek_r.txt','w',encoding='utf8') as f2:
        f2.write(re.sub(r'\r?\n(\D)', r' \1', f1.read()))
```

The `\r?` is added to match an optional CR symbol (if the line break is of Windows style). The `r'\r?\n(\D)'` can be replaced with `r'(?u)\r?\n([^\W\d_])'` to only match a line break that is followed with a *letter* (`[^\W\d_]` matches any char other than a  non-word, digit and `_` chars, i.e. any letter). The `(?u)` is an inline `re.U` modifier version to match any Unicode letter in Python 2.x (in Python 3, it is used by default).

Output:

```
Blessed is a Man

1. μακάριος ανήρ
2. ότι γινώσκει κύριος
```

Comment: on my macOS Sierra is not working, is there I way to fix for mac?

Comment: @Andrei Try `r'(?:\r\n?|\n)(\D)'`. It will match all 3 variations of a line break: `CRLF`, `LF`, `CR`. Or just replace `\r?\n` with `\r`.

Comment: your code need `content=f1.read()` and with `r'\r?\n(\D)'` is working! by the way what should I change in my code above which is reading line by line in order to work, because `r'\r?\n(\D)'` in my code gives nothing?

Comment: @Andrei Sorry, I copied it wrongly  from my console. Yes, the `f1.read()` is a must, no need to even create a separate variable. *what should I change in my code above which is reading line by line in order to work* - you might read a line, save it into a variable, and only write a line break if the current line starts with a digit.

Comment: thanks for suggestions, I spent a lot of time without notice that in my code, computer is reading line by line but when it reads the second line it clears from memory the first one